# Unable to get value from mobx store in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to get a value from @computed get getCategories() function but whenever I try to call this function I am getting  this error

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'any[]' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I am calling the function like this

```
 this.store.getCategories().then(res =>{
  console.log(res);

})
```

The getCategories function in my mobx store is like this

```
 @computed get getCategories(){

        console.log('these are the acategories',this.categories)
        return this.categories
    }
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

full mobx example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v3mwd5

unless `getCategories` returns a promise, I think you have structured the method call incorrectly.

if store is structured like this

```
export class Store {
  @observable cartItems = [];
```

And the computed function like this

```
@computed get cartSize() {
    return this.cartItems.length
  }
```

I access `cartSize` like this, notice it is not a function

```
this.store.cartSize
```